# Which response belongs to which task in a node.js threadPool?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, callback, threadpool, web-worker

Imagine you are going to have a lot of long processor intensive tasks of translating some strings into something else. You are going to want to have a pool of actual threads to keep the main node thread going and to make use of your cores.

The main way to do this is to either implement [Threads-a-gogo](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) or [Webworker-Threads](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo), and start a pool of 16 threads (e.g. on a Intel with 8 cores you usually have 16 threads concurrently).

Doing a request to a thread is called an event or a message. Getting a response is also catching an event or getting a message. But how does this work with a threadPool?

If you skip the Webworker API, TAGG and Webworkers for node have the same underlying API. You can load your translation function in all workers using `threadPool.load` and que a task to one of them using `threadPool.any`.

But imagine I now have 50 tasks (strings to translate) to be queued. The `threadPool` will eventually emit 50 events (responses with a translated string) without telling me what task the response belongs to?

I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding one thing about the threadPool.

Is there a way I can just add a task to the threadPool queue and receive a callback when **that particular task** is done?

Answer (score 1):

Why emit events from the thread pool when you can just return the translated string? The value returned by the code is received by the callback you passed to `threadpool.any.eval()`. Example:

```
threadPool.any.eval('return "hello world"', function(err, data) {
  // data === 'hello world'
});
```

Comment: This might be just what I need. I am close to accepting this. I was so focussed on the webworker API (node-webworker-threads) and the `onmessage` `event` that I didn't play close enough attention to `eval`; I thought it was an inline-variant of `load`, which also has a cb, but I thought for when loading the initial function (not executing it) was done. Is there a way to emulate this behavior using Webworkers API?

Comment: With Web Workers, you only have `postMessage()` and there is no built-in thread pool. However if you want to re-use a worker, what you'd have to do to match up callbacks with work requests would be to pass in some kind of unique id with the request data so that the worker can `postMessage()` with both the result and the original id so you can match up the callback.